# WPF 4 keyboard focus: never recieving key events

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, keyboard-shortcuts, wpf-4.0

In WPF 4.0, I can't seem to get any keyboard shortcuts to work if I swap the user control in the window after it's been loaded. A code sample says a thousand words, so here's what I'm doing:

```
Window window = new Window { Width = 800, Height = 600 };
window.Loaded += delegate
{
    editor = new EditorRoot();
    window.Content = editor;
};
app.Run(window);
```

`window` gets KeyDown events (and routed commands work fine), but `editor` never gets any keyboard events (nor do any controls within it). I tried:

```
editor.Loaded += (sender, e) => Keyboard.Focus(editor);
```

... but that didn't do anything. `EditorRoot` extends `UserControl` and has `IsFocusable=true` Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And if this does not work - use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. From my experience - setting focus synchronously doesn't always work. And not only in WPF 4.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try the `FocusManager` instead of your approach. I use it and it works, you can even use it in XAML:

```
         FocusManager.FocusedElement=editor;
```